# Jenkins Console Output showing extra information

Tags: c#, jenkins, console

I am using Jenkins to launch and monitor our automated regression test tool. The tool itself will display information using C# and Console.WriteLine();  This works fine on the screen.

```
TestTool.exe - 1.1.5976.16032
Copyright (c) 2014

REPLAY   1 of 197 20160511_1904-50\mantis6937_005             OK
REPLAY   2 of 197 20160511_1904-50\mantis6937_004             OK
```

However, when I look at the information in the Jenkins Console Log, it seems to capture some Font informaiton?

```
REPLAY   1 of 197 20160511_1904-50\mantis6937_005                  Black
Bold
Book
Condensed
Demi-Bold
East
...
Upside-Down
West
    OK
REPLAY   2 of 197 20160511_1904-50\mantis6937_004                  Black
Bold
Book
Condensed
Demi-Bold
East
...
Upside-Down
West
    OK
```

C# code static class

```
    public class ConsoleUtilities
    {
        public const int FILE_NAME_SPACING = 35;
        public const int STATUS_SPACING = 10;

        private static bool UseColor_ = true;
        public static bool UseColor
        {
            get {   return UseColor_; }
            set {   UseColor_ = value;  }
        }

        public static string ApplicationVersion
        {
            get {
                Assembly MyProgram = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
                return MyProgram.GetName().Version.ToString();
            }
        }

        public static void ShowText(string[] HelpText, string LogPathFileName) {
            foreach (string HelpLine in HelpText) {
                ShowText(HelpLine, System.ConsoleColor.Gray, System.ConsoleColor.Black, LogPathFileName);
            }
        }

        public static void ShowText(string HelpLine, System.ConsoleColor Foreground, System.ConsoleColor Background, string LogPathFileName) {
            ShowTextOnConsole(HelpLine, Foreground, Background, true, LogPathFileName);
        }

        public static void ShowText(string HelpLine, string LogPathFileName) {
            ShowTextOnConsole(HelpLine, System.ConsoleColor.Gray, System.ConsoleColor.Black, true, LogPathFileName);
        }

        public static void ShowPartialText(string Text, string LogPathFileName) {
            ShowTextOnConsole(Text, System.ConsoleColor.Gray, System.ConsoleColor.Black, false, LogPathFileName);
        }

        public static void ShowPartialText(string Text, System.ConsoleColor Foreground, System.ConsoleColor Background, string LogPathFileName) {
            ShowTextOnConsole(Text, Foreground, Background, false, LogPathFileName);
        }

        private static void LogText(string LogPathAndFileName, string Text, bool AddNewLine) {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter Output = new System.IO.StreamWriter(LogPathAndFileName, true)) {
                if (AddNewLine) {
                    Output.WriteLine(Text);
                } else {
                    Output.Write(Text);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ShowTextOnConsole(string Text, System.ConsoleColor Foreground, System.ConsoleColor Background, bool AddNewLine, string LogPathFileName) {
            if (UseColor_) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = Foreground;
                Console.BackgroundColor = Background;
            }
            if (AddNewLine) {
                Console.WriteLine(Text);
            } else {
                Console.Write(Text);
            }
            if (UseColor_) {
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
            if (LogPathFileName != "") {
                LogText(LogPathFileName, Text, AddNewLine);
            }
        }

        public static string FormatFileDisplayStatus(string FileName, string Status) {
            return FormatFileDisplayStatus(FileName, Status, FILE_NAME_SPACING, STATUS_SPACING);
        }

        public static string FormatFileDisplayStatus(string FileName, string Status, int FileNameWidth) {
            return FormatFileDisplayStatus(FileName, Status, FileNameWidth, STATUS_SPACING);
        }

        public static string FormatFileDisplayStatus(string FileName, string Status, int FileNameWidth, int StatusWidth) {
            string FormatedText = "".PadRight(2) + FileName.PadRight(FileNameWidth) + " - " + Status.PadRight(StatusWidth);
            return FormatedText;
        }

        ~ConsoleUtilities()
        {
        }
     }
}
```

The internal UseColor_ is false in this example, so the console colors are not being changed by this function.

What is interesting is the initial launch of the program will show console output, that does not have the font capture issue.

```
string[] AboutText = { 
    "TestTool.exe - " + CSharpUtilities.ConsoleUtilities.ApplicationVersion,
    "Copyright (c) 2014",
    ""
};
ConsoleUtilities.ShowText(AboutText, LogPathFileName);
```

This code produces information on the log without the font information being captured.

```
TestTool.exe - 1.1.5976.16032
Copyright (c) 2014
```

This is printed into the log before the first test, without any issues as well.

Comment: If you comment out that log line does the font information still get raised? i.e. could it be some other code in your component or a library that you're using that's also writing logs?

Comment: @Rup I commented out the log with no change. I have updated the question with the complete class. Interesting note that the initial program dump does not have the problem, but the partial line dumps do.